# Choosing the order that text fields cycle when tab is pressed

Tags: cocoa, textfield

I have several text fields and would like to set a particular order in which they would cycle when the tab key is pressed. Currently, it starts at a text field with `becomeFirstResponder` and then goes on in the default order which xcode put. Can I somehow bypass that order and force the text fields to cycle in a particular order? Like linking the last one of the cycle back to the first one.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connect the `initialFirstResponder` outlet of your window to the first text field, then build a chain by connecting the `nextKeyView` outlet of that text field to the text field that should come next (and so on).

Comment: Don't forget to set `previousKeyViewLoop` so that shift-tab knows what to go back to.

Answer (score 4):

That's called [the key view loop](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH7-SW9).